# HTML Alert - Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to call this upload script in an `html alert` in the spreadsheet:
[drive-multi-upload](https://github.com/CharlesPlucker/drive-multi-upload)

For that I'm using this function in the `Code.gs` file:

```
function showDialog(){                                              
const TEMPLATE = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms'); // calls the html page where the alert template will be
    
const HTML = TEMPLATE.evaluate().setWidth(600).setHeight(400); // we prepare the template to be loaded

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HTML, " "); // we load the template on the screen
}
```

The issue is that if another account clicks the button to upload the file, the message `Exception: Unable to retrieve the next object: the iterator has reached the limit.` is displayed.

How can I resolve this?

**Edit:**

looking at the execution log I have this here:

```
Exception: Unfortunately, a server error has occurred. Wait a moment and try again.
    at getParent(Code:12:25)
    at eval([unknown file]:110:56)
    at eval([unknown file]:368:3)
    at doGet(Code:2:59)
```

My `Code.gs` file is exactly like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms.html').evaluate();
}


function getOAuthToken() {
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}

function showDialog(){                                           //for show the msg to the user
   const TEMPLATE = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms');// chama a página do html onde estará o template do alerta

  const HTML = TEMPLATE.evaluate().setWidth(600).setHeight(400);// preparamos o template para ser carregado
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HTML, " ");// carregamos o template na tela
}

function getParent(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  var parent = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents().next().getId();
  return parent
}

// função para executar um script no mobile
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}

/**
* creates a folder under a parent folder, and returns it's id. If the folder already exists
* then it is not created and it simply returns the id of the existing one
*/
function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
  try {
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId),
      folder;

    if (parentFolder) {
      var foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video");
      if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
        video_folder = foldersIter.next().getFoldersByName(folderName); //folderName esta definido no arquivo forms.html
        if (video_folder.hasNext()) {
        folder = video_folder.next();
        }
      } else {
        folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video");
        folder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
    }

    return folder.getId();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

// NOTE: always make sure we use DriveApp, even if it's in a comment, for google to import those
// libraries and allow the rest of the app to work. see https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
```

Comment: If your executing through `doGet()` there is no active spreadsheet.

Comment: How do I get around this? As I mentioned, my goal is to open the upload script through a button on the worksheet. With my Google account it works, but with others it doesn't.

Comment: Solved, basically it is not enough for the worksheet to be shared with the other account, it is necessary to share the folder where the worksheet is for the script to work. But now I'm curious, is there a way for this to work without me having to share the folder with the account? This would be useful as I wouldn't want the person to have access to the contents of the folder.

Comment: I'm not sure of the work process because you don't show your `forms.html` but your function  `createOrGetFolder` creates a new folder.  So if another user is trying to execute this function they need permission to do that.

Comment: Through the `Web App` the person can upload without having access to the folder, because it is possible to enable the execution of the script with my account, the point is that I do not know if it is possible to open the `Web App` in the `HTML alert`, apparently it is only possible to call a Google Apps Script `HTML file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki since the solution was provided by the OP and @TheWizEd in the comments section.

The issue was related to the permissions of Google Drive that do not allow the script to create folders inside his structure since his users do not have access to the main folder.

The solution was to share the main folder with the users.

As an extra, I searched if there was an option to allow apps script to run as a specific user, and you might try impersonation. However, there is no direct library from Google for impersonation in Apps Script; you will need to search for 3rd party.